# Xpath get value from parent node of siblings

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, parent-child, siblings

Currently I have some xml structure like this:

```
<element type="Input" name="nationality">
   <property i18n="true" text="Nationality" prefix="person.nationality."
    name="caption">caption</property>
   <property i18n="true" text="Nationality" prefix="person.nationality."
    name="desc">desc</property>
   <property name="visible">1</property>
   <property name="mandatory">0</property>
   <property name="value">AUS</property>
   <restriction prefix="country." base="String">
    <enumeration text="Albania" value="ALB" />
    <enumeration text="Algeria" value="DZA" />
    <enumeration text="Argentina" value="ARG" />
    <enumeration text="Australia" value="AUS" />
    <enumeration text="Austria" value="AUT" />
    <enumeration text="Bahrain" value="BHR" />
   </restriction>
</element>
```

I would like to ask is there any way using xpath to extract value of enumeration[@text] tag with value equals with text in property[@name='value']. In this case the expectation text "Australia".

It's just a first time I use xpath, any idea will be appreciated. Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
/*/*/enumeration[@value = ../../*[@name = 'value']]/@text
```

Answer (score 3):

**Use**:

```
/*/restriction/*[@value = /*/property[@name='value']]/@text
```

This selects any `text` attribute of any child element of `/*/restriction`, whose `value` attribute is equal to the string value of a `property` child of the top element, that (the `property` child) has a `name` attribute, whose string value is the string `"value"`.

**If you don't want to select the attribute, but just its string value, use:**

```
string(/*/restriction/*[@value = /*/property[@name='value']]/@text)
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select=
  "/*/restriction/*[@value = /*/property[@name='value']]/@text"/>
==========
  <xsl:value-of select=
  "string(/*/restriction/*[@value = /*/property[@name='value']]/@text)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<element type="Input" name="nationality">
   <property i18n="true" text="Nationality" prefix="person.nationality."
    name="caption">caption</property>
   <property i18n="true" text="Nationality" prefix="person.nationality."
    name="desc">desc</property>
   <property name="visible">1</property>
   <property name="mandatory">0</property>
   <property name="value">AUS</property>
   <restriction prefix="country." base="String">
    <enumeration text="Albania" value="ALB" />
    <enumeration text="Algeria" value="DZA" />
    <enumeration text="Argentina" value="ARG" />
    <enumeration text="Australia" value="AUS" />
    <enumeration text="Austria" value="AUT" />
    <enumeration text="Bahrain" value="BHR" />
   </restriction>
</element>
```

**the two xpath expressions are evaluated against the above document and the string values of the results of these evaluations (properly delimited) are copied to the output**:

```
Australia
==========
  Australia
```